# What are Fowler's guidelines for comma usage for this phrase?

Tags: commas, legalese, style-manuals

I don't need to set off "at times" in commas here, do I?

> "It is an at times fraught debate... "

The alternative is as follows:

> "It is an, at times, fraught debate... "

And, a second question, is "at times" in this clause an adverb modifying the adjective "fraught"?

And, if I'm right to think there's no such thing as a compound adverb, I need not concern myself with hyphens here (ie, "at-times"), need I?

I'm editing a peer-reviewed work and am chary of rephrasing at a late stage of the process. It's for a law journal, and the guide is [Fowler's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Modern_English_Usage); I could find nothing there of assistance on this point, however. (That's not to say there's nothing there to help me!)

Comment: "It is a debate at times fraught with ..." or "At times, it is a fraught debate ..." would obviate the question.

Comment: Thank you Kit, but I'm editing a peer-reviewed work and am chary of rephrasing at a late stage of the process...

Comment: Oh, is it for a journal? Do you have a particular style guide that you are expected to follow?

Comment: Yes, thanks Kit, it's for a law journal, and the guide is Fowler's; I could find nothing there of assistance on this point, however. (That's not to say there's nothing there to help me!)

Comment: Comma use is often a matter of style preference, so the guide you are using is pertinent to the question. I'll adjust your tags as well.

Comment: I edited your comments into your question and made the title pithier. If you don't like the edits, you can roll them back.

Comment: "*It is, at times, a debate fraught with <...>*"  It's ***a*** not ***an*** regardless of where the parenthetical is placed.  Although I suppose if you hyphenated:  "It is an *at-times-fraught* debate" then it could be *an*.

Comment: I suspect that your compound adverb question would be better off as a separate question so it can get unique attention; I can answer questions about Fowler's opinions much more confidently than I can about edge case sentence diagramming, and lumping them together in one question reduces the change *either* will get answered well. (It also, and perhaps more importantly, makes voting on answers difficult, which impacts the usefulness of the site's sorting mechanics.)

Answer (score 1):

As always, Fowler has an opinion. It's not about structure though--it's about adding punctuation to clarify what is already clear. In **Parenthesis, 3.** he describes "readiness to resort to parenthesis where it is irrelevant" as "fatal." (By "parenthesis" he's referring to inserting of related information to the flow of a sentence using a stop regardless of whether the stop is square or round brackets, dashes, or commas.)

Since the meaning of the sentence is equally clear with and without commas, **Fowler would have you leave them out.**

Answer (score 1):

**"It is a debate at times fraught with ..."** or **"At times it is a fraught debate ..."** are both correct, as other commenters have pointed out.

Only a law student would write something as clumsy as **"It is an at times fraught debate.... "**

See, for example, the New Yorker cartoon where the welcome mat (which might as well be at the front door of a law firm) reads, **"Not Unwelcome"** http://tinyurl.com/Law-Office-Cartoon